# How to resolve a shift/reduce conflict forcing a shift or a reduce?

Tags: grammar, bison, yacc, shift-reduce-conflict

When there is a shift/reduce conflict in Yacc/Bison, is it possible to force the conflict to be solved exactly as you want? In other words: is it possible explicitly force it to prioritize the shift or the reduce?

For what I have read, if you are happy with the default resolution you can tell the generator to [not complain about it](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Expect-Decl). I really don't like this because it is obfuscating your rational choice.

Another option is to rewrite the grammar to fix the issue. I don't know if this is always possible and often this makes it much harder to understand.

Finally, I have read the precedence rules can fix this. I clueless tried that in many ways and I couldn't make it work. Is it possible to use the precedence rule for that? How?

Though my ambiguous grammar is very different, I can use the classical if-then-else from the [Bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Shift_002fReduce) to give a concrete example:

```
 %token IF THEN ELSE variable
 %%
 stmt:
   expr
 | if_stmt
 ;

 if_stmt:
   IF expr THEN stmt
 | IF expr THEN stmt ELSE stmt
 ;

 expr:
   variable
 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it is not possible to direct the parser to resolve a S/R conflict by choosing to reduce. Though I might be wrong, it is probably ill-advised to proceed this way anyway. Therefore, the only possibilities are either rewriting the grammar, or solving the conflict by shifting.

The following usage of right predecence for `THEN` and `ELSE` describes the desired behavior for the `if-then-else` statement (that is, associating `else` with the innermost `if` statement).

```
%token IF THEN ELSE variable
%right THEN ELSE

%%

stmt
    : expr
    | if_stmt
    ;

if_stmt
    : IF expr THEN stmt
    | IF expr THEN stmt ELSE stmt
    ;

expr
    : variable
    ;
```

By choosing right association for the above tokens, the following sequence:

```
IF expr1 THEN IF expr2 THEN IF expr3 THEN x ELSE y
```

is parsed as:

```
IF expr1 THEN (IF expr2 THEN (IF expr3 THEN (x ELSE (y))))
```

and Bison does not complain about the case any longer.

Remember that you can always run `bison file.y -r all` and inspect `file.output` in order to see if the generated parser state machine is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the default resolution for a shift/reduce conflict is to shift, so if that's what you want, you don't need to do anything (other than ignoring the warning).

If you want to resolve a shift/reduce conflict by reducing, you can use the precedence rules -- just make sure that the rule to be reduced is higher precedence than the token to be shifted.  The tricky part comes if there are multiple shift/reduce conflicts involving the same rules and tokens, it may not be possible to find a globally consistent set of precedences for the rules and tokens which resolves things the way you want.